# Why does global template function not visible inside member function?

Tags: c++

The following code [doesn't compile](https://wandbox.org/permlink/au91bEN6WcAGY3Ds):

```
template <class T>
void f(T t) { }

struct S {
    void f(int, double) {}
    void f() { f(42); }
};
```

Error is:

> ```
> no matching member function for call to 'f'
> ```

If I explicitly add `::` before `f(42)` code [will be well compiled](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FTzOIW4mHvvdFjg4). 
Why does global template function with the same name as member function (but different number of parameters) not visible inside class namespace?

Comment: Scoping rules: member functions shadow global functions, they're not treated like overloading.

Comment: Research the subject of *name hiding*.

Comment: It's a scope thing - local names hide names in outer scopes.